# How can I check for the existence of at least three digits in a string?

Tags: c, string, if-statement, input, passwords

I am currently working on the following task:

> A good password must have at least a minimum length of 8 characters and needs to contain at least three digits.
>   Write a C program to check whether a password is good or not a password returning true or false.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    char password[100];
    bool hasupper = false;
    bool haslower = false;
    bool hasdigit = false;

    scanf("%s", password);
    if(strlen(password) < 8)
    {
        printf("Too short");
    }
    for( int i = 1; i < strlen(password); i++ )
    {
        if(isupper(password[i]))
        {
            hasupper = true;
        }
        if(islower(password[i]))
        {
            haslower = true;
        }
        if(isdigit(password[i]))
        {
            hasdigit=true;
        }
        if(hasdigit && hasdigit && hasdigit && haslower && hasupper)
        {
            printf("true");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("false!");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am still confused how to make it check for the existence of at least three digits.

How can I make it check for the existence of at least three digits?

Comment: Change `hasdigit` to be `num_digits` instead. That is, count rather than just a flag.

Comment: `int i=1`. Arrays in C start from index 0. Did you mean to skip the first character?

Comment: @kaylum for  input:lalapolo                                                                                                               I get Tryagain!Try again!Try again!Try again!Try again!Try again!Try again!

Comment: huh? What is that in reference to? There is no "Try again" in your code. And did you change your code? Please don't add updates to comments. Edit your original question with any code updates and changes in behaviour. We can't help if the code you are looking at is different to what we can see.

Comment: @kaylum sorry I get this: `FalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalse`

Comment: You aren't checking for 3 digits, you're checking for **a** digit. You should change it so that instead, you count the number of digits you find in the string. If they exceed 3, well, that's it.

Comment: @Frontear I added a counter  `int digitcounter=0`and `digitcounter++` After the if statement. But i still always get the same output `falsefalsefalsefalse`.

Comment: Please please update your question with the latest code. You are wasting people's time as you are talking about code we can't see.

Comment: You should update your original question with this new code. It'll help us see where you might still be having a problem.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question, formatting the code to make it more readable, removing irrelevant details, and giving it a better title and problem statement. You should look closely at the changes I made and take them into consideration the next time you ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't checking if the string contains 3 digits, like you specify. Rather, it's only checking for the existence of at minimum, a single digit. Typing the `hasdigit` condition 3 times isn't going to evaluate it differently, it's just like writing `true && true && true` or `false && false && false`.

You should instead create an `int` that counts the amount of digits you find, then check if `count >= 3`.

```c
int main(void) {
    char password[100];
    int digits;
    // hasupper, haslower have been removed, since your original question doesn't actually specify them as necessary. Feel free to put them back if they are.

    scanf("%s", password);
    int len = strlen(password);

    if (len < 8) {
        printf("Too short.");
        return; // or exit, or whatever
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (isdigit(password[i])) {
            ++digits;
        }
    }

    if (digits >= 3) {
        printf("Good password");
    }
    else {
        printf("Not so good password");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I use a while loop to keep checking if the length is greater than 8.

Comment: `while( strlen(password)<8) {
        printf("Too short\n");
        scanf("%s", password);
        }`

Comment: Absolutely, you could just loop right there and grab a new password in your while loop.

Comment: @trelelelee Accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: You should probably mention that there should be checks in `scanf`, mainly `%99s` for the password.